# LazyLoad Plugin by Mika Tuupola not working on Iphone 5/4s but works on ipad 3 using iOS 6.1

Tags: iphone, ios, jquery-plugins, iphone-5, lazy-loading

I'm having an issue with lazyload on the iphone 5 and 4s.  For some reason, when I scroll down the page, it loads two images in the viewport, when there are 9 in the viewport, then i scroll down, only another 2 images are loaded, and again, etc.  When I click the home button and go back to safari on the iphone 5, it then loads all the images in the viewport.  I don't have an iphone 5 but i tested it at the apple store, I have an ipad 3 and it works fine on that.  If anybody has any experience with this, any help would be greatly appreciated.  I'm hoping Mika can chime in on this as well as he's active here too.  Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

after fixing some bugs, it appears to be working. had some problems with the viewport other minor css bugs, and now it works perfect.